# Where should I store images for my android app? How to store and retrieve those images?

Tags: java, android, android-image

The app is an online app. And the size of my app (.apk) is already over 85mb. I want to store the images I am using on "some" server, instead of drawable folder. The problem is I don't know the particular server, and how do I store and retrieve the those images?

The app is written in java language.
It's an app to locate charging station for electric vehicle.

So, please give me some "servers" on which I can store images, and use them as and when reguired.

Comment: Check out Firebase Cloud Storage and Glide:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui

Comment: Ok, thank you! Is there any other alternative which might use less data?

Comment: Welll...no. You either have them locally or you have them on a server. Having them locally as drawables, assets or raw files will increase your app size. Having them on a server means you need to download them at least once. Afterwards, they can be retrieved from local cache but then your app takes up more storage on user's devices.